# How send proper timestamp to influxdb with influxdb-python

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have influxdb database `test` with measurement:

```
name: mes1
time          Amount     Buy_order_id Price     
----          ------     ------------ -----     
1529832177822 0.02294    132868375    130117.83
```

I would like to make graph in Grafana, but all data are in year 1970. I have other measurement:

```
name: cpu_load_short
time                Bool_value Float_value Int_value String_value host     region
----                ---------- ----------- --------- ------------ ----     ------
1257894000000000000 true       0.64        3         Text         server01 us-west
```

This time works fine. I figure out, that time in measurement `cpu_load_short` are stored in ns, but data in measurement `mes1` are stored in ms.

I receiveing time for `mes1` from websocket. Time for `cpu_load_short` is generated from python:

```
datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

All data are sent to influxdb via influxdb-python. I tried to adjust time for `mes1` and add six zeros in the end of number:

```
'1529832177822' -> '1529832177822000000'
```

but I received:

```
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

How can I send data to influxdb and make graph from it, so the data will be in proper format and the right date? Maybe I missing something but I can't figure out why I cant send data to my database in ns but I can send it with datetime. Could anybody explain me, where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue and was able to solve it, let me try to guide you.

When you write your points to InfluxDB using the influxdb-python client you can specify the time precision in the `write_points` method. (http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.DataFrameClient.write_points)

An example:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
client = InfluxDBClient(host=host, port=port, database=database)
client.write_points(value, time_precision='ms')
```

This will convert your `ms` to `ns` for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: What if you're using the `SeriesHelper` class?